# Unable to consume WCF service in mvc5 application when trying to get through add service reference

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

Hi I am developing small application using WCF,MVC4 and angularJS. I am refering following URL

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AngularJS-Shopping-Cart-8d4dde90#content

When i tried to add service reference in my mvc application I am getting below error

```
Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.
```

I gave below url to access service.

```
http://localhost:55835/Service1.svc
```

When i tried I am getting error. I am unable to add service reference in my application. I am little worried about my web.config file. This is my web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors> 
        <behavior> 
          <webHttp helpEnabled="True"/> 
        </behavior> 
      </endpointBehaviors> 
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Can someone tell me something I am missing anything in config file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>` behavior to your config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is displaying because you are not enabling metadata.Metadata(wsdl document for your service code) is neccessary because your client will generate proxy class on the basis of your metadata(wsdl code). If you will not enable your metadata then your client will never know how to implement the same kind of code in its's proxy classes.And this can be enabled under servicemetadata tag under servicebehavior tag by setting httpGetEnabled to true.

Add this line of code under servicebehavior tag just after  `</endpointBehaviors>` tag.(please do not include `<behaviour>` tag again)

```
<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="true"/>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```